# Non-repeating way of creating animations

Tags: wpf, vb.net, expression-blend

I have five labels in my application. namely `lbl1`, `lbl2`, `lbl3`, `lbl4`, `lbl5`

When `mouse` goes `over` `lbl1` the `fontsize` of `lbl1` becomes `24` from `16`.
At the same time the `layout width and height` also `increases`.
Also the `color` of `lbl1` changes to `red` from `white`.

When `Mouse` `leaves` the lbl1 all the above procedure is repeated in `reverse` order.

I want to do the same thing with `all the labels` mentioned above.

I am using `expression blend`, `wpf`, `vb.net`.

At least can any one suggest me a `tutorial` or a `query` to search on `google`?

**EDIT :**

```
<Window ....>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MenuItem_MouseOver">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontWeight)" Storyboard.TargetName="lblCompany">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontSize)" Storyboard.TargetName="lblCompany">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="26.667"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="lblCompany">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="130"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="lblCompany">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="50"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MenuItem_MouseLeave">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontWeight)" Storyboard.TargetName="lblCompany">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <FontWeight>Normal</FontWeight>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontSize)" Storyboard.TargetName="lblCompany">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="26.667"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="21.333"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="lblCompany">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="130"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="102"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="lblCompany">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="50"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="38"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter" SourceName="lblCompany">
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="MenuItem_MouseOver_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource MenuItem_MouseOver}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave" SourceName="lblCompany">
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="MenuItem_MouseLeave_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource MenuItem_MouseLeave}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelMenu" Height="65" Margin="122,0,278,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label x:Name="lblCompany" Content="Company" Margin="0,17,0,18" Width="102" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="38" Foreground="White" FontSize="21.333" Template="{DynamicResource lblMenuTemplate}"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblMasters" Content="Masters" Width="86" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="38" Foreground="White" FontSize="21.333" Template="{DynamicResource lblMenuTemplate}"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblTransactions" Content="Transactions" Width="127" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="38" Foreground="White" FontSize="21.333" Template="{DynamicResource lblMenuTemplate}"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblReports" Content="Reports" Width="82" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="38" Foreground="White" FontSize="21.333" Template="{DynamicResource lblMenuTemplate}"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblSettings" Content="Settings" Width="88" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="38" Foreground="White" FontSize="21.333" Template="{DynamicResource lblMenuTemplate}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a control template for label as shown in this msdn [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752327.aspx) . 
After that you need to define triggers to change font, size and color. 
Check this forum post on [triggers](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/909058c0-bdce-413b-96d7-a6b05f548079/setting-a-labels-border-with-mouseover)

Try these and let me know if you need more help on this

**EDIT:**

No need to use storyboard here. We can achieve this easily using Control Template and Triggers. Check the code

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="LabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
                        <Border>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                           />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />

                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelMenu" Height="65"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label x:Name="lblCompany" Content="Company"  Width="102" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="38"  Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" />
            <Label x:Name="lblMasters" Content="Masters" Width="86" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="38"  Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" />
            <Label x:Name="lblTransactions" Content="Transactions" Width="127" Height="38" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" />
            <Label x:Name="lblReports" Content="Reports" Width="82" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="38" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblSettings" Content="Settings" Width="88" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="38" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"  />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I don't know much about XAML. But I have tried as you suggested. But I don't get the results. I have tried it using Expression Blend. And I will edit my questions in a few minutes with the automatically generated XAML.

Comment: Though this problem is solved from XAML point of view but it is not solved from Blend's point of view. because I always hate to Write XAML if that's done in Blend with a few clicks.

Answer (score 2):

Hi i have created sample based on your requirement.

```
XAML
 <Grid Background="Black" >
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>                                  
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Label Content="First Text"/>
        <Label Content="Second Text" Margin="30 0"/>
        <Label Content="Third Text" Margin="30 0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```